# How do you indent using a keyboard shortcut in Google Keep if you have a non-US-keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-keep

How do you indent using a keyboard shortcut in Google Keep if you have a non-US-keyboard layout?

On a Swedish keyboard on a Mac I used <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> and the keys to the right of `P` (<kbd>Å</kbd> and <kbd>¨</kbd>) to indent and outdent respectively. (To indent I only needed <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Å</kbd>, but the key next to <kbd>Å</kbd> is a dead key making <kbd>⌃</kbd> necessary to "trigger" it for this purpose)

(I will add this as answer in 48 hours, the previous paragraph is just to remember it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Swedish keyboard on a Mac I used <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd> and the keys to the right of `P` (<kbd>Å</kbd> and <kbd>¨</kbd>) to indent and outdent respectively. (To indent I only needed <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Å</kbd>, but the key next to <kbd>Å</kbd> is a dead key making <kbd>⌃</kbd> necessary to "trigger" it for this purpose)